# cronjob not working on live server but works on localhost using crontab

Tags: php, localhost, cron

I have written this command in my localhost crontab

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://localhost/whitelabel/cms/cronjobs/calculatestats.php
```

and it works fine on localhost (ubuntu 12.04), but on my live server (Cent OS) i have added this command

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://liveserver.com/whitelabel/cms/cronjobs/calculatestats.php
```

but its not working. Although if i run this server file URL in browser, it works, but i have to run it through cronjob. I have also given the permissions to access this file but its not working in cronjob.

Comment: are you able to execute the command from terminal on liveserver?

Comment: yes i have executed it as you said.
on live it says :failed: Connection timed out. but on local it says: connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 471 [text/html] Saving to: /dev/null' 100%[===========================================================================‌​==========================>] 471 --.-K/s in 0s 2013-04-19 18:56:45 (24.1 MB/s) - /dev/null' saved [471/471]

Comment: I expected this. :).. Seems that the server cannot DNS resolve itself. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you need to run this via the web server? For a cron job I'd create my PHP file thus:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?
// /usr/local/bin/php -q is path to your PHP CGI file - any host should have one of these
// code here
?>
```

and run it thus:

```
*/1 * * * * /path/to/file.php >/dev/null
```

do a chmod 755 on the file first, and make sure you uplaod it in ascii mode

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just run:
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null -q http://liveserver.comwhitelabel/cms/cronjobs/calculatestats.php

In console? Usually I find that the error appears when I try to run the command without using the cronjob.

Compare what that command is doing on your local machine to what it's doing on the server without the chronjob and see if you can find your answer :)

Comment: on live it says :failed: Connection timed out.
but on local it says:
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 471 [text/html]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

100%[=====================================================================================================>] 471         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-04-19 18:56:45 (24.1 MB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [471/471]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 liveserver.com
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response
i have added the above line but it is still not connecting... Failed: connection time out... Retrying goes on ....

Comment: can you ping liveserver.com (from liveserver.com) ?

Comment: i have tried to ping but i think its not working.
ping liveserver.com says :
PING liveserver.com 56(84) bytes of data
and then nothing appears next, same goes on localhost

Comment: You see, this is a network problem. It's hard to fix this on SO. If I could see a terminal on that machine I could fix it

Comment: ok ... thanks a lot dear .. let me try once more ... and hope this time it gets solved